# How to find peaks by comparing with neigbhour points

Tags: qgis, raster, r, clustering

I have a raster layer with 3 bands
band1 - elevation data
band2 - x-coord
band3 - y-coord

I want to run  a grid of 9*9 cells over this raster layer staring from top-left to bottom-right row-wise and to get the peak (highest altitude) out of the neighboring cells in the current 9*9 grid and put that peak into a 2D-matrix which contains XY coordinate of the corresponding peak after completing the iteration, I will be left with a matrix of coordinates I came to know that `grid` function from raster package in R will be useful any more methods.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the answers in [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79801/how-to-calculate-peaks-in-a-dem).