# Extracting peaks and cols from a DTM raster and convert them into point shapefiles (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, extract

I’m trying (again) to find an automatic way to extract peaks and cols from a DTM raster (derived from LiDAR surveys).

By “peak” I mean simply the cell with the highest value of a neighbour of cells;

By “col” I mean the lowest value of a ridge that divides two water basins which “connects” two areas of higher elevations (that possibly culminate in their respective peak). This concept is related to the prominence of a peak as depicted in this figure:

[image]

I’ve searched some similar topics on this and most of the threads converge to r.param.scale algorithm and r.geomorphon but even spending some time trying several different combinations of their parameters none of them gave me a satisfying result.

As for the definitions I’ve given to peaks and cols, the r.param.scale algorithm on QGIS actually analyses the DTM to find peaks and cols (saddles) but It’s very far from being precise and consistent.
If I leave all parameters as default I get as a result that many of the features are not correctly classified (omitted or misplaced). Here’s an example:

[image]

In this case, the peak on the lower-right corner of the screen is correctly classified as a peak, conversely, the other peak is omitted (and adjacent to some cells classified as “col”). Nearby there are some cells that seem correctly representing the col between these two peaks.

If I increase the threshold of the first parameter (slope tolerance) the omissions decrease, but many other cells are classified as peaks or cols incorrectly:

[image]

With r.geomorphon (QGIS) the matter is quite similar. It seems slightly more consistent in classifying peaks, but has no classification for cols:

[image]

Here, what I don’t understand is why, for example, the lower-right peak is classified with many adjacent cells, while conceptually the peak should be one and one only cell (except in cases with cells with the exact same DN, but I’ve confirmed it’s not the case).

The ideal solution for my case would be classifying peaks and cols as single, isolated cells, then converting DN values to shapefile points. Even more useful would be the possibility to set thresholds to limit the classification, for example, by prominence. This would avoid the over-classification of features due to surface roughness.

Since the main threads on this topic are already some years old, is there any new advanced tool/plugin/script that may extract this information? I mainly use QGIS.

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to focus on one software stack. Specifying two is likely to get this post closed as lacking *focus*.

Comment: You used `r.param.scale` but please take a look at the much more powerful https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.geomorphon.html

Comment: Impossible to answer this without your data

Comment: @markusN I've used also r.geomorphon, it's written in the main post. It seems a little more accurate than r.param.scale, but it classifies peaks as clusters of cells even if the real peak should be only one cell

Comment: @BERA it's a normal DTM raster. Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QXA62JEQh0xmLliZ74A6OYaWq-A3KciC/view?usp=sharing
The data is projected in EPSG 3003 and the peak is at coordinates 1614510, 4737730

Comment: @BERA this is only an example. This concept should be applicable to every raster since it has to do only with the raster's DNs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all about definitions. If you assume that your peak is any cell, that is higher than 8 of its neighbors, you'll pick any tiny bump in your terrain:

[image]

However if definition is any cell that is highest for neighborhood square 101*101, you'll get this:

[image]

To locate mountain passes you'll need to isolate ridges first. Picture below shows divides between watersheds (**catchments**) greater than 10,000 cells:

[image]

Use cells under divides as a mask for your analysis, i.e. limit focal statistics to the cells underneath mask. This time compute **minimum** for neighborhood square:

[image]

Unfortunately this discards passes on the ridges inside watersheds. To overcome that I'd compute divides between same size **subcatchments** to use as a mask raster.

Perhaps correct order is defining ridge cells first and proceed with peaks, cols after.

I'll keep [peaks and cols zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4ex1Zp7GjBTr59sNQZ_qtH7OBvacIHm/view?usp=sharing) for next couple of days.

Difference of peaks and mean value of neighbors will give you a 'prominence'.

Comment: It might be useful to incorporate Topographic Position Index and Slope Position classifications in the workflow to further define relief features http://www.jennessent.com/downloads/tpi-poster-tnc_18x22.pdf

Comment: That looks good! I've compared your results with the data I've had already produced some time ago for that territory with a manual workflow and the peak extraction is really accurate. There are some that are missing but I guess is due to the neighbourhood square set to 101x101. 
I'd ask you, which tool did you use to scan the raster with arbitrary neighbourhood square dimensions?
One more thing: Cols have been as well extracted with the same neighbourhood square, right?

Comment: I used ArcGis tool 'Focal Statistics', similar should exist in Qgis, because it's basic numpy function. You can also specify circle instead of square neighborhood.  Yes, for cols, see layer name.

Comment: Most tricky part are ridges. Most certainly they are divides of smaller subcatchments  if you're going to pick them inside basins shown, but you'll need to eliminate stream cells, because they will also pop up as cols. Making hundreds of 'same' size subcatchments is also not easy. I use python for that.

Comment: @FelixIP Thank you for the explanations. I'd ask you one more passage I'm still missing since I'm not much practical of ArcGIS. Once I've computed the Focal Statistics on the raster, how do I extract the points from that data?

Comment: This is raster calculator expression Con(dem >= FSTAT, dem). This is essentially IF statement meaning condition. Follow by raster to points. Use less or equal for passes.

Comment: Now it's all clear. Thank you very much! I think I can reproduce this workflow also in QGIS and then I'll make some attempts on how to set small subbasins for ridge detection.