# Determining optimal tower placements that use line of sight in a valley in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst, viewshed

I am currently working on a project to determine the proper placement of towers that rely on line of sight to work in a large study area in a valley with 2 large sets of mountains on either side. I was hoping to get some opinions as to what would be the best method to use to do so.

My thought process was to divide the study area by half using the centerline of the valley (also trying to figure out how to do that through model builder). and generate a large number of points within each side of the valley and then insert those points into the line sight tool to allow for the determination of line of sight or create a viewshed of some sort to determine optimal placements.

I am new to 3D line of sight work.

Comment: How many towers total?

Comment: @FelixIP It's not so much the towers but the areas where these towers could be placed if that makes sense. I probably should have clarified that a little better. which is why i am having a hard time figuring this out

Answer (score 0):

This task is **mostly** about number of towers, because it's enough to find [dominant peaks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421141/extracting-peaks-and-cols-from-a-dtm-raster-and-convert-them-into-point-shapefil/421173#421173) and run your analysis on them. If it is about single place, you need to run viewshed N times, where N is total number of peaks. So, for 26 peaks shown:

[image]

It takes 26*30 sec/run = 13 minutes. /I am dealing with DEM made of 13.6M cells/. Which is not a big deal. Doable for 10 times larger set of points, esp. on machine with GPU. However if I am allowed 2 towers we are looking at 162(!) minutes for the same tiny set.

See if you can modify script below to suit your purposes. It computes pair which result in minimum of not visible cells over specified DEM. Note peaks are not necessarily to be on watershed line.

```
import itertools as itt
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = 'in_memory'
sMax = 1e12
FIDS = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("DOMINANT","OID@")
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"DOMINANT")[0]
for pair in itt.combinations(FIDS["OID@"],2):
    q = 'OBJECTID in %s' %str(pair)
    lyr.definitionQuery=q
    outViewshed = Viewshed("DEM",lyr)
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(outViewshed, "vShed_View", '"Value" =0', "", field_info="OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;Value Value VISIBLE NONE;Count Count VISIBLE NONE")
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("vShed_View","COUNT") as cursor:
        for row in cursor: AR = row[0]
    arcpy.management.Delete("vShed_View")
    arcpy.management.Delete('in_memory')
    if AR<sMax:
        sMax = AR
        bp = pair
        print pair
lyr.definitionQuery=""
print sMax, bp
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Note that best pair of towers does not include highest peak.

Comment: How would it work to create more than one best pair? my current study area is a long a valley with a lake at its center and I'm trying to create a series of best pairs along it. I am unfortunately unfamiliar with arcpy, would i need to run it multiple times to try to find a series of them?

Comment: In example shown script ran viewshed tool 325 times, so learn coding. Humans don't live long enough to do it manually