# Identifying and replacing specific pixel in DEM using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, dem, editing, pixel, spatial-outliers

I have a DEM that has a handful out outliers, but I have no idea where they are within the DEM. I'm using ArcGIS Pro and I have used the outlier tool to try to identify the offending pixels, but there are some significant terrain features in the DEM that get rounded up with that tool.

Is there a way I can use the histrogram to find the minimum value, select that pixel, and then interpolate its value from its neighbors?

I've played around with the pixel editor for awhile and I just can't seem to get it to do what I need it to do.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.1.

Comment: Use focal statistics similar to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421141/extracting-peaks-and-cols-from-a-dtm-raster-and-convert-them-into-point-shapefil#421173 to locate them and replace by mean. Play with radius size if there are more than single cell that jumps out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use several ways to locate the offending pixels. If the raster is small enough simply turn it into a point dataset, you can then select the pixels of interest, now represented as a point, by the gridcode field.

If you want to keep it as a raster then use the CON() tool to extract out the pixels but be aware the pixel is exactly that a pixel and would likely be invisible at the full raster extent.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It's working. I found that I had some severe outliers clustered in a corner, and now I'm adjusting their values manually.